# Second order linear differential ODEs Reduction of order method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

### Background

> **1.4.1 Reduction of Order**
>
> If a solution $y_1(x)$ of the homogeneous Linear ODE (1.2) is known, then a second linearly independent solution $y_2(x)$ can be found by solving a **first-order** linear differential equation. A solution of (1.2) is sought in the form
>
> $$y=u(x)y_1(x),\tag{1.4}$$
>
> where $u(x)$ is a new unknown function. Inserting (1.4) into the homogeneous Linear ODE (1.2) and collecting terms with $u,u'$ and $u''$, we find
>
> $$u''y_1+u'(2y'_1+py_1)+u[y''_1+py'_1+qy_1]=0.$$
>
> The last term on the left-hand side is zero because $y_1(x)$ is a solution of (1.2), and we arrive at a first-order differential equation with respect to $U(x)=u'(x):$

---

> $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$
> $$y(x)=y_1(x)u(x)$$
> $$u''y_1+u'(2y'_1+py_1)+u(y_1''+py_1'+qy_1)=0$$

### The Question

Can someone please explain in layman's terms why $y_1(x)$ being a solution means that the last term on the left hand side is zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have a differential equation:
$$y''+py'+qy=0$$
Then $y_1$ is a solution of the DE this means:
$$y_1''+py_1'+qy_1=0$$
This is why $u(y_1''+py_1'+qy_1)=0$.